# sub() function in awk not working as expected for some strings

Tags: awk, substring

```
BEGIN { 
       str = "Sorecheck.o"
       print str
       sub(".o", ".src",str)
       print str
    }
```

Output:

```
Sorecheck.o
.srcrecheck.o
```

Expected Output:

```
Sorecheck.o
Sorecheck.src
```

I wanted to replace ".o" with ".src" but here sub() is omitting "." character while comparing. can some one tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Tried but no luck.  Here is the output.
Sorecheck.o
.srcrecheck.o
awk: main.awk:4: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'

Comment: @Myanju, try changing it to `sub(/\.o/, ".src",str)` once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. It's working :) Can you please explain this? Thank you.

Comment: @Myanju, why its working because we are making it as a regexp, if you put it inside `"` then you need to double escape it actually.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Tried with double escape it's working. What are the other characters needs to be escaped like this?

Comment: @Myanju, may be you could check this link once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions